# Why can't a Java Generic implement an Interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Is there a logical reason why E cannot implement my interface HasName?

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E extends HasName> {
    // stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `extends` keyword applies to interfaces too. That is:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E extends HasName> {
```

Means that `E` must be a type that extends a class, or implements an interface, called `HasName`.

It is not possible to code `E implements HasName` - that is implied by `E extends HasName`.

Comment: This much more clear for rookies like me than the answer in the original question it's marked duplicate of.